# Select a dummy column with a dummy value in zend frame work 2

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

```
$SQL = "SELECT '' as name,'' as id  FROM `student`"
```

if do like this errors are showing

```
$select->columns(array(''=>'name'));
```

is there any alternate way?

Comment: show us full code of your model. it absolutely unclear what is your goal because `SELECT '' as name,'' as id  FROM \`student\`` is invalid mysql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order of column name and alias needs reversing:

```
SELECT '' as name

$select->columns(array('name' => ''));
```

Column name '' needs to be used literally as it's not a column name, you can use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression:

```
 $select->columns(array('name' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('')));
```

Comment: if null is included then it is working ie.  new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('null ')